# Call method from regular ClassLibrary within .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-standard

## Background

We're changing a few items on our project and I've stumbled on an integration issue.

There are some 3rd. party DLLs written on regular ClassLibrary (.NET 4.0) and our project is now on .NET Standard + AspNet Core. We must update the whole infraestructure while keeping everything working.

## Structure

- SomeExternal.dll (3rd party code written in .NET 4.0)
- SomeFramework.dll (NETStandard 2)
- App_1 (.NET 4.7.1)
- App_2 (AspNet Core)

`App_1` calls `SomeFramework` which then calls `SomeExternal`.
`App_2` also calls `SomeFramework` which then calls `SomeExternal`.

This is done to prevent direct calls to `SomeExternal`. This is a requirement from the project which cannot be changed.

## Problem

How can I reference `SomeExternal` into `SomeFramework`?
I've tried direct assembly link (Add References > Assemblies > Search) but `SomeExternal` fails to load.

I've set the whole project to x64 or x86 (instead of AnyCPU) but nothing changed.

We're using VS2017 15.5.5, .NET 4.7.1 and .NET Core SDK 2.1.4.

Comment: I think this will help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions

Comment: @apomene That would be to change from version 1.0.1 to 1.0.2, no?

Answer (score 2):

.NET Core fully supports .NET Standard 2.0, which itself has a wide-enough API footprint that Microsoft has added native support for .NET Framework libraries. In other words, if you're running .NET Core 2.0+, you can add a reference to any .NET Framework library you want.

You will, however, get a warning. The warning, though, is simply to let you know that while you *may* be able to fully utilize the library, there is a possibility that it uses APIs which are not supported. It's on you to test and verify that everything works correctly, and then you can safely suppress the warning, if you like.

Mostly, those unsupported APIs at this point would resolve around Windows-specific functionality. Since .NET Core and .NET Standard are cross-platform, an API that is only for Windows would not be among the API footprints of either. However, even then, there is the [`Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility) NuGet which extends .NET Standard to support some of those missing APIs. However, this NuGet is only intended for migrating an application to .NET Standard/.NET Core, not as a long-term solution. The goal should still be to move away from this unsupported APIs to ones that actually are supported and cross-platform.

You should also employ the [API Analyzer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/10/31/introducing-api-analyzer/), which will call out usages of deprecated and unsupported APIs both in old code and new. That way, as you're working, you can see things that still need to be ported and be reminded if you revert back to using something that you shouldn't.

Comment: Done that. Read the problem section of the question. Should work? yes. Does it actually work? no. The only way to add this reference in order for it to work properly is through Nuget? Also remember that since I'm loading a 3rd party DLL I can't guarantee much. Loading from full .NET project works fine, but though core fails.